# AttributeError When Calling a Class with Another Class

Tags: python

I have this code within a classless function:

```
        while room.getNumCleanedTiles() < min_coverage * room.getNumTiles():
            for index in range(0, len(roboList)):
                room.cleanTileAtPosition(positionList[index])
                roboList[index].updatePositionAndClean()
                positionList[index] = roboList[index].getRobotPosition
                count += 1
```

- `positionList` is a list of positions of the class `Position`.
- The `position` class has two methods, `getX` and `getY`.
- The `room` variable is a room of class `Rectangular Room`, which has a method known as `cleanTileAtPosition`, which takes a position as its argument and does some operations using the `getX()` and `getY()` methods.

The code is too large to reasonably attach here in its entirety, but the problem seems to be localized to the methods and classes I have described. I am getting an error that states:

```
"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getX.'"
```

However, through print statements it is clear that `positionList[index]` is indeed a position of class `Position`; that `room` is a `RectangularRoom`; and that `getX()` and `getY()` work on the position when they are called independently of the `cleanTileAtPosition`.

Is there anything about this code that seems like it would raise the error I am getting?

Comment: Seeing your classes will be added benefit.. Also, we don't see `function` object here..

Comment: Judging from what I can see from your code, are you sure you're calling the `function.getX()` and not `function.getX`?

Comment: The error should give you some traceback. Could you post it? Are you sure you don't have a variable somewhere that you think corresponds to a class instance but that got renamed and is now a function?

Comment: If the exception is happening from inside `cleanTileAtPosition`, show us _that_ function, not some other code that calls it. Also, show us the results of the print functions, and try printing `dir(param)` as well as `param` to verify that it really does have a `getX`. Clearly what you're calling `getX` on is a function object, which means it's _not_ a Position.

Comment: @Pat: How could that possibly cause this problem? If `foo.getX()` works, `foo.getX` can never throw an AttributeError. (Well, if you really screw with the descriptors you can make that happen—e.g., make getX a `@property` then delete its get function—but the error still won't be the one shown above.)

Comment: @abamert: I was completely guessing, since there wasn't much code to go off of.  But I wasn't too far off, eh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `()` after getRobotPosition.